# Copyrights disappearing at certain scales on GoogleEarth Pro

Tags: cartography, google-earth, google, google-earth-pro, copyright

I want to use a map (scale 1:10000) of a city (Montreal). I assembled it from several high quality pictures.

We need to cite copyrights from GoogleEarth Pro. I have read online resources :
[permissions page](https://www.google.com/intl/en_en/permissions/geoguidelines/attr-guide.html)

Despite trying this, when zooming in, copyrights displayed before (e.g. Cnes Spot/image, DigitalGlobe) disappear so I cannot cite anything for this map at this scale.

Does it mean that GoogleEarth is the sole mention I should make? Is it a bug?

Comment: I believe the citation relates to the image that is displayed (e.g. if you're at a scale where a satellite image appears, you'll get the citation for that). If you zoom in, you're likely on aerial imagery, where the citations will be different. I don't have a reference though, so you probably should ask the right legal people. I'd also check that aggregation you're doing is compliant with the terms of usage at the same time.